# How to decrease microphone buffer size

Tags: windows-7, sound-card, microphone, buffer

How do I decrease the microphone buffer size on a Windows 7 Home Premium machine (Sony Vaio notebook)? Sound card is "Realtek High Definition Audio".

EDIT: "When recording audio into your computer, your sound card needs some time to process the incoming information. The amount of time allotted for processing is called the Buffer Size" (https://www.izotope.com/support/kb/index.php/kb/article/503-What_is_Buffer_Size_and_why_is_it_important)

For a live application, I need the lowest possible latency and, thus, try to adjust the buffer size. However, I simply can't find it...

Comment: Welcome to SUper User. Please take a minute to **[edit]** your question to include what you mean by *microphone buffer size* and what you have tried to resolve this already.

Comment: It might be application level - what are you using for recording?

Comment: Flash Media Live Encoder. There I can choose the device, set format and quality, but again no buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Start > control panel > Hardware and sound > sound

Right click on your microphone and go to properties

Go to level tab and you can reduce the microphone buffer

Comment: I've tried that already. There is only Volume and Amplification, no buffer.

Comment: Input level is the amount of gain applied to the incoming signal.  It has nothing to do with the buffer size.  The input buffer size is the number of audio samples that are received in one audio callback.  A smaller buffer reduces the latency, since it represents a smaller timeslice.  It is also more sensitive it is to dropouts, since it must be polled more frequently and is more susceptible to timing variations in the operating system's process scheduling.  Getting acceptable latency with no dropouts is a balancing act.